# How to convert money to decimal in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have stored procedure where want convert money type to decimal type.

`@money = 513.9010 type money`

I want to convert it to `decimal` - how to do that?

Answer (score 6):

```
select convert(decimal(7,4),@money)
```

Comment: Sonam thank you for answering, can you explain me what you mean in (7,2) ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx

Comment: With Decimal Datatypes we can optionally use precision and scale. Precision is the maximum total number of decimal digits that will be stored, both to the left and to the right of the decimal point. The precision must be a value from 1 through the maximum precision of 38. The default precision is 18.
And Scale is the number of decimal digits that will be stored to the right of the decimal point. This number is subtracted from p to determine the maximum number of digits to the left of the decimal point. Scale must be a value from 0 through p.

Comment: Also we can just use select convert(decimal,@money), so in this case there will be no decimal point.

Comment: If you convert to decimal(7, 2), you will lose some precision, and I'm not sure this is intentional or not.  money and smallmoney both can accommodate 4 decimal places: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179882.aspx  The OP does not indicate why he wishes to do the conversion in the first place.